# How do I get CIPAddressCtrl to support tabbing between tuple fields using period

Tags: mfc

You must actually be editing a tuple to get the dot to behave as desired.  So if I want to change 10.0.1.10 to 10.0.1.11, I must type "10.0.1.11" because the dot does NOT behave like a TAB.  I would like to type just "...11", but the dots are ignored until you are editing a tuple.  Doh!

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Does the system send an [IPN_FIELDCHANGED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/ipn-fieldchanged) message, when you enter a `.`?

Comment: No, it does not.  I am monitoring that notification along with the EN_CHANGE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IP address control does not respond to `'.'` unless the cursor is at the end of the sub field edit control, only then, it will move to the next field.

Override `PreTranslateMessage` in parent window/dialog to change the default behavior. The code below adds optional support for tab as well.

```cpp
BOOL CMyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG *msg)
{
    if(msg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        CWnd *focus = GetFocus();
        if(ip_address.IsChild(focus))
        {
            //don't proceed unless the field is set
            if(focus->GetWindowTextLength() && (
                msg->wParam == VK_DECIMAL ||
                msg->wParam == VK_OEM_PERIOD || 
                msg->wParam == VK_TAB))
            {
                //undocumented method to find the current field:
                int field = GetWindowLongPtr(focus->m_hWnd, GWL_USERDATA);

                //set focus to next field:
                if(field >= 0 && field < 3)
                {
                    ip_address.SetFieldFocus(field + 1);
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(msg);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I will probably not do the TAB because I actually have 4 CIPAddressCtrls on the same dialog, hence user may want to easily tab between those quickly, but utilize dot (glad to see VK_* , necessary when looking at WM_KEYDOWN).  Will check it out Monday and let you know then.

Comment: I added wrapping, so I tweaked field range to be inclusive `if (field >= 0 && field <= 3)` and also `SetFieldFocus((field+1)%4);`

Comment: I had to make one other adjustment, the wParam comparison for `'.'` is not valid for WM_KEYDOWN.  That numerical value for `'.'` matches VK_DELETE.  You do NOT want to "tab" when you hit the Delete key.  I tested it with and without NUMLOCK on, and it works as expected (deletes when NUMLOCK is OFF, TABs when NUMLOCK is ON since it is a VK_DECIMAL or VK_OEM_PERIOD (i.e. one of the other two wParam values)

Comment: Oh right, I shouldn't have put `'.'` in there. Removed in edit.