# Shift focus from CIPAddressCtrl to another control on pressing of tab key in C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

How to shift from one CIPAddressCtrl to another control with tabbing?
Like when user tabs at the end bit of an IP Address field, the focus should shift to the next control. 
GetNextDlgTabItem accessed with parent returns the ID of the current CIPAddressCtrl and not the next control's.

This is the code for the custom edit boxes which works:

```
CWnd *pWndCtrl = GetFocus();
CWnd* pParent = pWndCtrl->GetParent();
CWnd *pNext = pParent->GetNextDlgTabItem(pWndCtrl); 
pNext->SetFocus();
```

Comment: The CIPAddressCtrl has been designed like this, don't fight it.

Comment: I have another custom control, CustomIPAddressCtrl which inherits CIPAddressCtrl. Is there some way to implement this feature seperately in my custom control.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get CIPAddressCtrl to support tabbing between tuple fields using period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011876/how-do-i-get-cipaddressctrl-to-support-tabbing-between-tuple-fields-using-period)

Comment: I had referred that but it's working only for tabbing Within a CIPAdressCtrl. But I need tabbing for both inside a CIPAddressCtrl and between various CIPAddressCtrls and other custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution, the GetParent() method was returning the Parent ID of the group control not of the Parent dialog as desired.
GetParent()->GetParent() gives the correct Parent Id.

```
CWnd *pWndCtrl = GetFocus();
CWnd* pParent = pWndCtrl->GetParent()->GetParent();
CWnd *pNext = pParent->GetNextDlgTabItem(pWndCtrl); 
pNext->SetFocus();
```